# Translating a sentence from a list to morse code from a dict

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

How do I translate a sentence I already put inside a list to morse code via  dictionary I also have? Code:

```
    print("Write your sentence:")
    running = True
while running == True:
    morsecode = {
    "A" : ".-", 
    "B" : "-...", 
    "C" : "-.-.", 
    "D" : "-..", 
    "E" : ".", 
    "F" : "..-.", 
    "G" : "--.", 
    "H" : "....", 
    "I" : "..", 
    "J" : ".---", 
    "K" : "-.-", 
    "L" : ".-..", 
    "M" : "--", 
    "N" : "-.", 
    "O" : "---", 
    "P" : ".--.", 
    "Q" : "--.-", 
    "R" : ".-.", 
    "S" : "...", 
    "T" : "-", 
    "U" : "..-", 
    "V" : "...-", 
    "W" : ".--", 
    "X" : "-..-", 
    "Y" : "-.--", 
    "Z" : "--..",
    "a" : ".-", 
    "b" : "-...", 
    "c" : "-.-.", 
    "d" : "-..", 
    "e" : ".", 
    "f" : "..-.", 
    "g" : "--.", 
    "h" : "....", 
    "i" : "..", 
    "j" : ".---", 
    "k" : "-.-", 
    "l" : ".-..", 
    "m" : "--", 
    "n" : "-.", 
    "o" : "---", 
    "p" : ".--.", 
    "q" : "--.-", 
    "r" : ".-.", 
    "s" : "...", 
    "t" : "-", 
    "u" : "..-", 
    "v" : "...-", 
    "w" : ".--", 
    "x" : "-..-", 
    "y" : "-.--", 
    "z" : "--..", 
    "0" : "-----", 
    "1" : ".----", 
    "2" : "..---", 
    "3" : "...--", 
    "4" : "....-", 
    "5" : ".....", 
    "6" : "-....", 
    "7" : "--...", 
    "8" : "---..", 
    "9" : "----.", 
    "." : ".-.-.-", 
    "," : "--..--",
    "" : "No valid input.",
    " " : " " 
    }
    eingabe = input()

    liste = list(eingabe)
    print(liste)

    for str in liste:
        print(morsecode[liste])
```

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: I had another version to only translate single letters that worked but I don't know how to make it work for a whole sentence, so what I have by now doesn't work as I want it to...

Comment: Read [ask], give a [mcve].

Comment: Instead of repeating the code for upper and lwoer case letters, you might just want to coerce your char to lower (or upper) before getting the value on the dict

Comment: You should move the dictionary outside the while loop as it gets created every iteration.

Comment: Stack Overflow has a few dozen other questions about [writing Morse code translators in Python](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=site:stackoverflow.com+morse+code+python). They may be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you dont need to do a list. Change last lines to:

```
eingabe = input()
for char in eingabe:
    print(morsecode[char])
```

Answer (score 1):

This will loop over and over again converting sentences to morse code

```
while True:
    string = input("Input a sentence: ")

    for char in string.upper():
        if char in morse:
            print(morse[char])
        else:
            print(char)
```

And its not necessary to have both upper and lower case letters in your morsecode dictionary. I.e:

```
morse = {
    "A" : ".-", 
    "B" : "-...", 
    "C" : "-.-.", 
    "D" : "-..", 
    "E" : ".", 
    "F" : "..-.", 
    "G" : "--.", 
    "H" : "....", 
    "I" : "..", 
    "J" : ".---", 
    "K" : "-.-", 
    "L" : ".-..", 
    "M" : "--", 
    "N" : "-.", 
    "O" : "---", 
    "P" : ".--.", 
    "Q" : "--.-", 
    "R" : ".-.", 
    "S" : "...", 
    "T" : "-", 
    "U" : "..-", 
    "V" : "...-", 
    "W" : ".--", 
    "X" : "-..-", 
    "Y" : "-.--", 
    "Z" : "--..",
    "0" : "-----", 
    "1" : ".----", 
    "2" : "..---", 
    "3" : "...--", 
    "4" : "....-", 
    "5" : ".....", 
    "6" : "-....", 
    "7" : "--...", 
    "8" : "---..", 
    "9" : "----.", 
    "." : ".-.-.-", 
    "," : "--..--",
}
```

Comment: You dont need it. Once the user has inputed their sentence, the code goes through every character in the sentence `for char in string.upper():` the `.upper()` in this converts the character to an uppercase character. Hence, you only need upper case chars in your `morsecode` dictionary as it's impossible to get a lowercase with `.upper()`

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't require a while loop and, if you do (to execute multiple times), there's no need to *redefine* the mapping for each iteration.

Apart from that, you're passing the *whole list* to the dictionary when you should be passing its elements (which you should be naming something like `i` not `str`). Since lists can't serve as dictionary keys (due to them not being hashable) this is an Error.

In short:

```
print("Write your sentence:")
morsecode = # as defined 
liste = list(input())
for i in liste:
    print(morsecode[i])
```

the list isn't required here because strings are sequences that you can iterate through, but, that isn't too much of an issue.

suffices. If you need to continuously get input then the while loop is needed but you also need a condition where the loop would `break`; not let it continuously execute.

Comment: SInc your are renaming the variable `i` is also a bad name - but  for when you have index numbers hen you have an enumerate. Just call it `char`. Also, no need for a list at all.

Comment: Thank you very much! The while loop just gives me the opportunity to type in multiple sentences without restarting the whole program :)

Comment: Does redefining every time make a big difference in terms of processing power? (maybe for more complex programs than this one?)

Comment: @scoperationX Yes it does